# JavaScript: Find all <href> links and add style tag to it with style details like font, color etc.

Tags: javascript, regex, hyperlink, href, inline-styles

I have a field where the user can enter some text including links etc. Once the data is saved and the text should be previewed I need to format all the links to a certain inline style tag set on the `<a href>`. There is no option to use CSS so it should be inline.

Example entered text:`Some text goes here. Please go to my web site, click here <a href="http://www.onewebsite.com" target="_blank">www.onewebsite.com</a>. Then some more text here…..with more links etc……`

Example text when it’s previewed:`Some text goes here. Please go to my web site, click here <a href="http://www.onewebsite.com" target="_blank" style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #fa860b;">www.onewebsite.com</a>. Then some more text here…..with more links etc……`

Note that **`style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #fa860b;"`** is now added on the `<a href>`.

How is that possible to do with JavaScript in a simple way? it would be some kind of function like:

```
function formatPreview(myText){
  defaultStyle="style=\"font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #fa860b;\"";
  myText = myText, find all a href and enter my defaultStyle 
  return myText
}
```

Please let me know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would you need JavaScript? This can be achieved with CSS.

Comment: Hi - one very important comment is that the this will be used in an e-mail meaning that the style should be inline. So I don't have any access to jQuery and CSS. All the HREF links needs to have the STYLE tag added so the links will render probaly in all e-mail clients.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regex for this. Simply add these styles to the link using `jquery` like this when you want to preview:

```
$("a[href='http://www.onewebsite.com']").css("font-family","Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif"); 

$("a[href='http://www.onewebsite.com']").css("font-size","12px"); 

$("a[href='http://www.onewebsite.com']").css("color","#fa860b");
```

@Edit: Well, as many have already commented on my most, you need to include jquery library in your HTML code

@Edit 2: If you can put an ID to the achor tag, you can use the following javascript

```
<a id="a1" href=".."></a>

var element = document.getElementById("a1");

a1.style.fontFamily = "Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif";

a1.style.fontSize = "12px";

a1.style.color = "#fa860b";
```

Comment: And where is the jQuery tag or a reference to the library on the post?

Comment: Not to mention it's completely wrong, looking for `<a><href='http://www.onewebsite.com'>Some text</href='http://www.onewebsite.com'></a>`

Comment: Hi, I won't have access to jQuery so it needs to be done with JavaScript and maybe with RegEx? Is that possible.....

Comment: It can be done with Javascript too. Let me come up with the code for that.

Comment: Hi @gurvinder372, unfortunately I don't have any option to put in an ID either. For some reasons I'm very limited. All links is like this <code>....<a href="http://www.onelink.com" target="_blank">my site</a></code>..... so I'm searching for a JavaScript function or RegEx that can do that for me since there is no option to use jQuery, CSS, getElementById etc.

Comment: Unless and until you have only one anchor tag, you need to give it a class or an Id, otherwise it won't be solved by regex either. Is it possible for you to wrap it in a div or <p> tag and give them an id?

Answer (score 1):

Why is there "no CSS option"? If you only want to affect links in the preview area, then (assuming your preview area has `id="preview"`) just do this:

```
#preview a {
    font-family: 'Arial', 'Verdana', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fa860b;
}
```

Comment: Hi, it's a preview process that will shown how the acutal text will look like. I can see that I forgot to mention that the text will be insereted into a html e-mail so that's the reason why I won't have access to jQuery and CSS linking. It's need to be inline style tag so the e-mail will render probaly in all e-mail clients.